# Styling a specific data-title-original

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a range of tooltips that were set up using PHP so that you can upload an image and then customise the tooltip information as you please.

All the tooltips are one size, but I'd like to set a specific size for one specific tooltip. I can't add a class to it because all the tooltips are set up using a PHP script.

I tried this css but it's not working:

```
    a[data-original-title="SABS APPROVED"] .tooltips button {width: 60px !important;}
```

Is there some jquery that can help me achieve this?

Here's the HTML:

```
     <div class="row tooltips-content">


                <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="SABS APPROVED">

                </a>




<div class="symbols">
<span class="tooltips " style="" title=""><button style="background-
image:url(http://javlin.unknowndesign.co.za/wp-
content/uploads/2017/06/SABS_APPROVED.svg);"></button></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML too

Comment: I just edited the question with the HTML @kapantzak

Comment: `.tooltips button` is not within `a[data-original-title="SABS APPROVED"]`

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS

```
a[data-original-title="SABS APPROVED"] .tooltips button {width: 60px !important;}
```

looks ok, maybe there is wrong select rule? For example, no need in space before .tooltips...

You also can add class via javascript (don't forget do it when document ready)

```
$('a[data-original-title="SABS APPROVED"]').addClass("my_special_tooltip");
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no `data-original-title` attribute in the HTML, second, there is no `tooltips` class in the HTML.

Let's assume this HTML structure:

```
<div class="row tooltips-content">
  <a href="#" class="tooltips" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="SABS APPROVED">
    <button>Button</button>
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

You do must remove the space before `.tooltips` to select all the elements that have this class and the specified attribute:

```
a[data-original-title="SABS APPROVED"].tooltips button {width: 60px !important;}
```

Comment: This still isn't working. 

I'd actually added the wrong HTML code, sorry, here's the correct one. 

So I'm trying to change the width of the tooltip button image when the data-original-title is SABS APPROVED